# Set complete background for Angular project

Tags: css, angular, background-image

I tried many times and searched a lot about how to set image background for whole app in angular project.

I tried global css and app.component.css but it just set background for component area.

Here is my global css file:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Vazir';
  background-image: url("assets/back.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I defined another css file and link in index.html but it didn't work well .I have also set directly into body tag in index.html but I got same result.

PS: I don't want to set pixels or percentage in css file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By global css file do you mean the styles.css?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in the following way:

1-Define a router outlet in the root component (probably app.component.html)

```
<div class="outlet-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

2- In the relative style file (app.component.css/scss), define:

```
.outlet-wrapper {
  background-image: url("assets/back.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: actually I dont have rounting in this project , It just consist of one component ( app.component) I followed your instruction but it didn't work .   here is my index.html code :<body>
  <div class="outlet-wrapper">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>

Comment: Add height and width properties if that's the case

Comment: you can add `min-height:100vh;min-width:100vw`

Comment: @Eliseo thanks, it's somehow works, But would you please explain more where to put this css statements, in global css or in appcomponent.css? thanks for your help